# Comma usage with "despite" and with two independent clauses

Tags: commas

I am trying to analyze the parts of the following sentence and I am stumped:

*According to last year's data, sales increased by 3.5% to 30 million US Dollars in 2019, and to 35 billion US Dollars in 2021, despite the COVID-19 pandemic.*

I am tripped up as to whether there should be a comma after 2019 and if there should be a comma before "despite."  If I delete a few words, it seems as though the comma doesn't belong: "According to last year's data, sales incrased to 30 million in 2019 and to 35 million in 2021."

I thought the phrase beginning with "despite" is a dependent clause, but I've done some searching on the internet that says it might be a prepositional phrase.  Which is correct/  And what is the proper comma usage?

Thanks!

Comment: Imho, the second comma, after 2019, is optional. I would keep it as a brief pause, for the sake of clarity, though.

Comment: ... while I would have thought the third comma separating 2021 from the pandemic is optional, but if it is removed then the second comma helps indicate that the pandemic did not affect 2019 events.

Comment: Where did you find this odd sentence? At best, you can analyze *and to 35 billion in 2021* as **nonessential, parenthetical content**, which is why it would be surrounded by commas. Like this: *According to last year's data, sales increased to 30 million in 2019 **(and to 35 billion in 2021)** despite the COVID-19 pandemic.* But that doesn't make much sense. And 30 **million** to 35 **billion**? That doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I found it on a grammar test--when I typed it in, I mistakenly switched "billion" to "million," so that is the reason for that particular error.

Comment: Yes, "despite the the COVID-19 pandemic" is not a clause but a preposition phrase. Omit the comma after 2021 in order to ensure that the PP is part of the second coordinate only. Alternatively, re-write it as _According to last year's data, sales increased by 3.5% to 30 million US Dollars in 2019 and, despite the Covid19 pandemic,  to 35 million US Dollars in 2021_.